# Floating arrow for expanding box (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am having trouble with adding a little "V" arrow to a expanding div on my page. 
I want to to sit on the border of the div and go down when the div expands (and possibly turn around into a "^" arrow)

But I have no idea how to get it to float ontop of the border, could anybody please help me or tell me how to tackle this problem?

Page: http://www.trulyscience.com/test/ (The question thing on the bottom right)

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/tJugd/1070/

I got a arrow at the bottom now, so the top one can also disappear when the div opens, but no idea if that is simpler :P

*updated tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it a slightly different way.  I would use the same div when open and closed, but change the class so that a different icon would appear.

Here we go: http://jsfiddle.net/tJugd/1091/

Is this what you were meaning?  Let me know if not.

EDIT - Just updated the demo to put the arrow in the center!

FINAL EDIT - added extra css and html to place arrow in white container div

Comment: Sounds good, I never really used classes so a example would be much appreciated :P

Comment: It doesn't seem to work completely: http://www.trulyscience.com/test/
It's not opening fully and the damn arrow won't center

Comment: I thought I did, but fogot to update the ".question" ones. Works well now, only thing that still bugs me is tat the gray border is a bit fattish because of the arrow. Can that be fixed? 


(you are awesome btw)

Edit: maybe putting the arrow next to the title would fix that. but they keep refusing to sit next to eachother.

Comment: added a white background to the arrow.